# What are the carbohydrates that are found in white rice?

Tags: biochemistry, food-chemistry

From this Wikipedia page on [rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice#Characteristics), it is mentioned that 100g of rice contains 80 g of carbohydrates, of which 0.12 g is "sugar" and 1.3 g is "fibre". I believe the "fibre" refers to dietary fibres that are not absorbed by the body and are just passed out of the body. However, I understand "carbohydrates" to be almost the same as "sugar" so what is the difference between the two terms as used in this context. I am guessing that "sugar" refers to simple monomeric units of carbohydrates while the rest of the "carbohydrates", excluding "sugar" and "fibre", is in the form of starch polymers, namely amylose and amylopectin. Could someone help to verify my understanding?

Comment: Fibre is contained in a particular form of starch, called resistant starch. Fibre, like sugars and starches, is a type of carbohydrate. However, fibre is different because it is not digested by the human body in the same way as sugars and starches. this is a good read from the 4th paragraph: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/305890780_Rice_as_a_Source_of_Fibre

Comment: The word carbohydrate is most common in biochemistry, where it is a synonym of saccharide, a group that includes sugars, starch, and cellulose. Starch (a polymer of glucose) is used as a storage polysaccharide in plants, being found in the form of both amylose and the branched amylopectin. In animals, the structurally similar glucose polymer is the more densely branched glycogen, sometimes called "animal starch".

Comment: @aliential you might consider putting your comments as answers instead, as they seem to actually answer the question rather than comment upon it.

Comment: Thanks, its just copy paste research...